# ggplot loess line from one dataset over scatterplot of another

Tags: r, ggplot2

The function below calculates binned averages, sizes the bin points on the graph relative to the number of observations in each bin, and plots a lowess line through the bin means. Instead of plotting the lowess line through the bin means, however, I would like to plot the line through the original dataset so that the error bands on the lowess line represent the uncertainty in the actual dataset, not the uncertainty in the binned averages. How do I modify `geom_smooth()` so that it will plot the line using `df` instead of `dfplot`?

```
library(fields)
library(ggplot2)

binplot <- function(df, yvar, xvar, sub = FALSE, N = 50, size = 40, xlabel = "X", ylabel = "Y"){
  if(sub != FALSE){
    df <- subset(df, eval(parse(text = sub)))

  }

  out <- stats.bin(df[,xvar], df[,yvar], N= N)
  x <- out$centers
  y <- out$stats[ c("mean"),]
  n <-  out$stats[ c("N"),] 
  dfplot <- as.data.frame(cbind(x,y,n))

  if(size != FALSE){
    sizes <- n * (size/max(n))

  }else{
    sizes = 3
  }

    ggplot(dfplot, aes(x,y)) +
      xlab(xlabel) +
      ylab(ylabel) +
      geom_point(shape=1, size = sizes) +
      geom_smooth() 
}
```

Here is a reproducible example that demonstrates how the function currently works:

```
sampleSize <- 10000
x1 <- rnorm(n=sampleSize, mean = 0, sd = 4)
y1 <-  x1 * 2 + x1^2 * .3 +  rnorm(n=sampleSize, mean = 5, sd = 10)
binplot(data.frame(x1,y1), "y1", "x1", N = 25)
```

[image]

As you can see, the error band on the lowess line reflects the uncertainty if each bin had an equal number of observations, but they do not. The bins at the extremes have far fewer obseverations (as illustrated by the size of the points) and the lowess line's error band should reflect that.

Comment: `?geom_smooth`, the second argument is `data`. Have you tried specifying `data = df`?

Comment: Please make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data so we can run the code.

Comment: @Gregor that yields `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found` I've looked at the ?geom_smooth and ?ggplot pages. This may be a completely noob question, seems like it should be straightforward, but I can't figure it out

Comment: @MrFlick just added a reproducible example of how it currently works. I tried adding one before I posted but all of R built-in datasets I tried were too small for binning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can explicitly set the `data=` parameter for each layer. You will also need to change the aesthetic mapping since the original data.frame had different column names. Just change your `geom_smooth` call to

```
geom_smooth(data=df, aes_string(xvar, yvar))
```

with the sample data, this returned

[image]